# Vb.net save data to db from BindingSource

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, bindingsource

I have a main form. With a button I open a dialog form with a DataGridView Binding to BindingSource1

On Closing form I use:

```
Private Sub OK_Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK_Button.Click
      If (Not SaveRecords()) Then
        If (MsgBox("Close whitout Save?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    Me.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Function SaveRecords() As Boolean
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        BindingSource1.EndEdit()
        Me.SalaTableAdapter.Update(Me.CassaMDataSala.Sala)

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

All is ok: I make change, insert, delete, closing the dialog form and reopen-it I see changes. But if I exit and re-enter from the program (closing the main form) the changes are not committed

Comment: Yes ,this is bound to happen  since when you exit the parent form the onClosed event of the child dialogue will not be invoked. You need to handle this in the on Closed event of the parent form as well , where you may check if the child dialogue is open you can then trigger the enemy of the child form

Comment: I add complete code and the form is TopMost

Comment: I dont understand: the OK button save records, but finaly de db dont recive changes